# Android normal button turns transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a background set with `android:background="@drawable/background"`.

In my RelativeLayout` I have a standard button but when I run the app in devices running 3.1 or higher the button are displayed transparent.

I have tried setting `android:alpha` to 1 with no luck.

I know I can make a custom background with selector and shapes but there has to be another way.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: That's just how buttons are styled on the later versions of Android. You'd need to override this look in your own theme or set a background on your buttons.

Comment: Ok, I have a own theme set that's inherits from Holo Light. How do I override the look of the buttons from there? Thanks @Rawkode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add something like this to your style.xml

**Application theme**

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtons</item>
</style>
```

**Button style**

```
<style name="MyButtons" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Make sure you're setting your theme correctly in the manifest also

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ApplicationStyle" >
```